# Replacing Gutter Fascia?

Tags: gutters, soffit, fascia

A decision must be made to determine whether to replace gutter fascia.  I am replacing a faulty / questionable soffit install:

[image]

I am at a decision-point: **if the fascia is to be replaced, now is the time to do so before any more soffit work.**

The photos below show replacing the soffits with radial pieces.  It also shows removal of the old gutter sections. Gutters were removed exposing the aluminum facia:

[image]

The remaining gutter in the left of the photo was installed 12 months ago and will be retained.

## QUESTIONS

There are a few small nail holes that could be filled in with sealant.  If there is no damage to the wood under the fascia:

```
What are the reasons to replace the exposed aluminum fascia?
How do I test said reason to determine if replacement of the section is necessary?
```

I intend to add gutters soon, however, I need to understand why I would want to replace the existing fascia, so I can develop a "litmus" test to decide whether or not to replace.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the aluminum fascia covering is sound (i.e. not bent all to hell or oxidized/corroded) and the wood underneath is in good shape, replacement criteria would be strictly aesthetics.

Yours looks bent up a bit and stained in places, but if it were mine I would attempt to (carefully) beat it back flat, caulk the holes, then hit it with a fresh coat of paint.